# How do I debug an application with command line parameter input in Qt with MinGW?

Tags: qt, debugging

I'm dealing with a program which needs command line input, i.e. `int main( int argc, char* argv[])`. I cannot debug this application since every time I press debug button, the program and GDB debugger just exits since no command line parameter were passed to the program. So what steps do I need to follow to solve this problem?

I created a Qt console application. Here is the code:

```
int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) {
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    if ( argc != 5 && argc != 8 ) {
        help( argv[0] );
        return -1;
    }
    //bla bla bla
    return a.exec();
}
```

Then I set a breakpoint and pressed <kbd>F5</kbd> to debug. After the black command line window appear, it shows the help() message and return. The IDE is Qt Creator3.0.1 with library 5.2.1.

Comment: Works without any problems for me in Qt Creator. Please add more details.

Comment: @PavelStrakhov I've added more info. BTW, do I need to change settings  under Tools->Settings->Debugger ?

Comment: Did you specify command line parameters at all? You can do it in Projects (in the left column) -> Run -> Arguments.

Comment: @PavelStrakhov It's the first time I know there is a way setting command line parameters, which confuse me for days. Thank you very much!

Comment: @PavelStrakhov There's another problem that the watch window on right column is either empty or variables with no value. How to deal with it please?

Comment: @PavelStrakhov You should write that as answer so it can be accepted by user957121 (I think this is valid question and it would be good if it had accepted answer).

Comment: @user957121 You should ask ask a new question if you have unrelated issue. But first go through toolchain debugger stuff in Options dialog, look for debugging helpers or something like that (and if not solved, include this in your new question).

Comment: @hyde Thanks for the hint. The reason is my computer is too slow and I need to wait for a while to get variable values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Qt Creator you can specify command line arguments in Projects (in the left column) -> Run -> Arguments. It works for both running and debugging modes.